# SQL computed column based on a special character on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns

I am not good with SQL at all, barely have an idea on how to do basic scripts suck as delete, drop, add.

I have this data with about 12 columns, I want to add a calculated column which will change depending if a special character shows up in another column.

lets say

```
A                 C   
Money$            YES
Money             NO
```

that is the idea, I want to create a column C where it says yes if there is a $ sign on the column A.  Is this possible? I am assuming you can use something similar to an if condition but I have no experience with SQL scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use a `case` expression and `like`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when a like '%$%' then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as c
from t;
```

The following is just commentary.

This is very basic syntax for SQL.  I would recommend that you spend some time to learn the basics.  Learning-as-you-go is an okay approach -- assuming you have some fundamentals to build on.  Otherwise, you are likely to spend a lot of time to learn a few things, and you may not learn the best way to do things.

Comment: how would I go about using your? select t.*, would I replace the t by something else?
nevermind, I was tinkering with yours, this was the code that solved my question :) it is really simple , I will keep reading a bit more on this types of functions, if you can recommend me a good resource, please let me know

Answer (score 4):

yes, this is possible. you'll have to replace the parts in braces (`{}`) with the appropriate object names. I also use a `bit` rather than `'Yes'`/`'No'`; as that seems better suited:

```
ALTER TABLE {YourTable} ADD {New Column Name} AS CONVERT(bit, CASE WHEN {Column} LIKE '%$%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) PERSISTED;
```

Note that this will return `0` if the column (`{Column}`) has a value of `NULL`, not `NULL`; unsure if this is the correct logic however, this should be more than enough to get the ball rolling. If not, read up on the `CASE` expression and `NULL` logic.

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '{'.

is what I am getting when using this. Dont know why

Comment: @VictorJMytre.... *"You'll have to replace the parts in braces ({}) with the appropriate object names."* You haven't replaced the parts in braces.

Comment: I did , but incorrectly, your answer also worked. a bit more complex than the other due to the bit, but I will use it for another calculated column :) thanks a lot!

Comment: So, for example @VictorJMytre , instead of `{YourTable}` you would put the *actual name* of **Your Table**.

Comment: Yes I understood that part, it was just that I forgot the prefix of my table and it was causing issues.

quick question, isee that my calculated columns are not showing in outside queries such as power bi, is there a way to make this columns on the databsae show for outside queries?

Comment: The above alters the table. You'll be able to see in any queries that reference that table; unless the (service) account has specific `GRANT` permissions on certain columns only. But then that'll be a conversation for your DBA, @VictorJMytre .

Comment: What if I wanted to instead of having a bit for 1 and 0, have a string? the yes no was an example but the idea was more of a string with other words , not a true or false situation.

Comment: Then change the logic of the `CASE` expression and get rid of the `CONVERT`, @VictorJMytre . If you don't understand the code above (including Gordon's) you shouldn't be using it. It's up to you to support it not us. If you don't understand, there's no time like the present to start learning about SQL (as it's clear you're lacking fundamental knowledge), and then read up on the `CASE` expression.

Comment: @VictorJMytre *"`incorrect syntax near '{'`"* There's still a brace (`{`) in your code... As I've said, *"You'll have to replace the parts in braces ({}) with the appropriate object names."* The fact you're getting an error near `{` clearly shows you haven't done so as those braces woudn't be in the code.

Comment: I saw the issue, I am just used to other coding where you put it between braces. I am still having issues with CASE , code says it is expecting a ( or SELECT where CASE is .

Comment: Have a look at my examples, @VictorJMytre. Seems like you're doing *something* wrong.

Comment: ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD Type AS nvarchar(max)( CASE when [Column A] like '%$%' then 'Special' else 'Common' end) PERSISTED;

is what I am using, but seems like it is not the correct syntax and cant find an example that uses a case like this.  My table has all string columns as nvarchar(max) and I used that type.  The column is named type and that might be causing an issue with syntax too.

Comment: What is `nvarchar(MAX)` doing there, @VictorJMytre ? Apart from that you don't define a computed column's data type like that, I severely doubt you need 2GB of space to store "Yes" or "No".

Comment: it just says that CASE has an incorrect syntax near it, expecting ( or SELECT......if I remove the data type it just says that the definition for the column Type must inclde a data type, I understand your point. but  I am asking about those issues I have with that code. I used nvarcharmax as an example.

Comment: Because you have a random `nvarchar(MAX)` in there, @VictorJMytre . I'm afraid I'm not here to help you learn the basics of SQL, sorry. Review my code, and the fiddle; if you don't understand it, then take the time to learn and understand those features. I suggest the following Google terms: [SQL Server CASE Expression](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+CASE+expression) and [SQL Server Computed Column](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+Computed+Column), and perhaps [ALTER TABLE SQL Server](https://www.google.com/search?q=ALTER+TABLE+SQL+SERVER).

Answer (score 0):

Regexp match can help you find out if there is a character you consider as special char in the strings:

```
SELECT
        ColumnA
    ,   SUBSTRING(ColumnA, PATINDEX('%[^ a-zA-Z0-9]%', ColumnA), 1) AS FirstSpecialChar
WHERE
    ColumnA LIKE '%[^ a-zA-Z0-9]%'
;
```

The pattern `[^ a-zA-Z0-9]` will match on any character which is not a number, a space or an alphabetic character (note the ^ at the beginning of the character group - that mean `NOT`)

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex to check any special character in column EX:
SQL SERVER

> SELECT CASE WHEN 'ABCD$' Like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as result

MYSQL

> SELECT CASE WHEN 'ABCD$' REGEXP '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as result

Regex can be changed as per the requirement

> REGEXP '[^[:alnum:]]'

Comment: *"You can use regex"* Apart from your can't, because SQL Server does not support REGEX and there is no `REGEXP` function in the T-SQL Dialect.

Comment: regex is replacable by like

Comment: That doesn't change my statement *"SQL Server does not support REGEX"*. It only supports basic pattern matching.

Comment: So you just want to change only $, if yes then you can write on '%$%' with the like, thats it. and if you want to remove all special character then you have to add all special characters.